# Database multiple choice and comments structure

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I've read a lot of pages but didn't find what I was looking for.
I am trying to figure out which is the most appropriate solution for my problem here. I currently got a multiple choice form with 23 questions and 23 comments section (650 characters each, basically a comment per question) and I am not sure if I should go with a single table or if that would be too much.

So basically something like:

```
id
user_id
date
multiplechoice1
..
multiplechoice23
comment1
..
comment23
status
```

That will be around 50 columns :/ Is there a better way to do this? Like split the comments on a different table or somehow combine all the multiple choices in a single column? Since each answer will be 1-5.

Example of the question:

### How long do you usually surf the NET on a daily basis?

- 0-1 hour
- 2-3 hours
- 4-6 hours
- more than 7 hours

Comment: Personally, I'd go 5 tables. `forms`, `questions`, `answers`, and then two relational tables: `form_questions`, and `question_answers`. Naming conventions personal preference, of course. All of your forms go in the `forms` table, questions in `questions`, answers in `answers`. Your `form_questions` table has two columns: `form_id` and `question_id`, where you list all questions for a form. The `question_answers` table also has two columns: `question_id` and `answer_id`, where you list all answers for a question.

Comment: @Santi The form with the questions is fixed there won't be added or removed anything for a long time (if anything is added/removed will be 1-2 questions). Is it worth it placing them in the DB in the first place though? Thanks!

Comment: If it is always going to be one fixed form then you don't have to worry about the `forms` or `form_questions` table. If you will **not** be re-using answers from question to question, then you won't need the `question_answers` table either. Though, the most I'd flatten the structure in your case is two tables: `questions` and `answers`. Have a `question_id` column in your `answers` table. That way, you could put 5 answers there, and set them all to `question_id: 1`, meaning question 1 has those 5 potential answers.

Comment: @Santi I've currently got all the questions and answers within a php file so if Q1 echo this question and answers and I was thinking to save the answer in a tinyint to know which answer the user chose and text for the comments. (See the edited version above)

Comment: If these questions are polling, rather than multiple-choice "correct / incorrect", then I'd include some sort of `selected_answers` table, where you just track the chosen answer for each question, very similar to the `question_answers` table I suggested earlier, but you're tracking the chosen answers instead of the possible answers.

Comment: @Santi Can you please give me an example when you've got some free time? So I can choose your answer too :) Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking your comments into consideration, being that you don't want to normalize too much and prefer something slightly flattened, I think this may be a proper solution for you.

`questions`

```
+----+-------------------------------+
| id | question                      |
+----+-------------------------------+
| 1  | What is your favorite food?   |
+----+-------------------------------+
| 2  | What is your favorite animal? |
+----+-------------------------------+
```

`answers` - question 1 has three answers, question 2 has two answers

```
+----+-------------+-----------+
| id | question_id | answer    |
+----+-------------+-----------+
| 1  | 1           | Spaghetti |
+----+-------------+-----------+
| 2  | 1           | Chicken   |
+----+-------------+-----------+
| 3  | 1           | Sushi     |
+----+-------------+-----------+
| 4  | 2           | Dog       |
+----+-------------+-----------+
| 5  | 2           | Cat       |
+----+-------------+-----------+
```

`answer_data` - one person answered "spaghetti" for question 1, one person answered "cat" for question 2, and one person answered "dog" for question 2

```
+----+-------------+-----------+
| id | question_id | answer_id |
+----+-------------+-----------+
| 1  | 1           | 1         |
+----+-------------+-----------+
| 2  | 2           | 4         |
+----+-------------+-----------+
| 3  | 2           | 5         |
+----+-------------+-----------+
```

Truthfully I'm not great with MySQL, I'm a T-SQL guy, but the query would probably look something like this:

```
SELECT q.question, a.answer, COUNT(ad.answer_id) as `Count`
FROM questions q
JOIN answers a ON a.question_id = q.question_id
JOIN answer_data ad ON ad.question_id = q.question_id
GROUP BY q.question, a.answer


+-------------------------------+-----------+-------+
| question                      | answer    | count |
+-------------------------------+-----------+-------+
| What is your favorite food?   | Spaghetti | 1     |
+-------------------------------+-----------+-------+
| What is your favorite animal? | Dog       | 1     |
+-------------------------------+-----------+-------+
| What is your favorite animal? | Cat       | 1     |
+-------------------------------+-----------+-------+
```

Comment: I think the only thing we are missing is the user_id from the answer_data (since I need to connect all those 23 questions/answers with the user) and a comment column that needs each answer. So for example `user_id = 1` `question_id = 1` with `answer_id = 2` and `comment = 500 chars of text`

Comment: Yep, apologies, didn't realize you needed those. Both can go in the `answer_data` table. Might want a datetime field there too so you know when they submitted it.